# show and hide form by one click and animation in with jquery in angular ( type script )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, typescript

i need to create a button for show and hide the form .

i create this form :

```
 <button type="button" (click)="ShowAndHide()"
  class="AddCatBtn">show and hide </button>
<div class="AddCategory">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="inputEmail4">Name : </label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4">
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and use this code in ts file :

```
   ShowAndHide(){
$( ".AddCatBtn" ).click(function() {
  $( ".AddCategory" ).toggle();
});
```

but i have problem with this code :

1 - i need to once click for show and hide but in this code i should double click for work show and hide form

2 - i need to when form is loaded , The form is hidden .

3 - i need to add jquery animation in this code for show and hide : like fade in and fade out .

this my demo code :

[My sample code](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

how can i solve These problems???????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're writing the app in Angular, let Angular take care of it. Don't do direct DOM manipulation the jQuery way.
Template:

```
<button type="button" (click)="ShowAndHide()" class="AddCatBtn">show and hide </button>
<div class="AddCategory" [class.hidden]="divIsHidden">
   <!-- rest of code... -->
```

CSS:

```
.hidden { visibility: hidden; }
```

TS:

```
public divIsHidden = false;

ShowAndHide() {
   this.divIsHidden = !this.divIsHidden;
}
```